# Serving an SPA from a WordPress install

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, single-page-application, vue.js

I'm building a Single Page Application (SPA), that is built as a single index.html files with a bunch of static resources. Because the SPA has routing logic, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, we need to serve this SPA from a WordPress install, so I'd have to make my index.html a theme template (no problem), but we can't seem to figure out how to approach the .htaccess.

Whatever we try, WordPress keeps trying to serve the files from its own paths.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

So to give a practical example

```
/img/*
/fonts/*
/app.css
/app.js
```

These files would live in a subdir called `/some-app`, the URL of the app would be `http://www.domain.com/some-app`, so technically resources would be served fro `http://www.domain.com/some-app/img/*` for example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the rewrite lines placed above the WordPress default lines in your WordPress htaccess file?

Comment: Those rewrite lines are not part of the WP .htaccess. They're the ones I use for my SPA build, which is a separate repo.

Comment: I see -- But hypothetically if that SPA app's directory exists, WordPress's routing rules wouldn't ever come into play. Anything in an actual directory "some-app" (or whatever) wouldn't be affected by the .htaccess file in the WP root directory. At least that's been my experience with most server setups

Comment: Therefore, it would seem you could just plop that SPA directory in WordPress root, and not bother with making it live "inside" wordpress (unless there's some other requirement I'm not sure of that necessitates this)

Comment: Interesting, it seems that works, let me give it a shot tomorrow, because that might save me a good amount of headaches. If it works, feel free to post it as the answer and I'll accept it ;-)

Comment: Awesome! I think it should work, maybe with a few small tweaks to workout along the way. Let me know if you have any success, and I'll post the above as an answer.